# Why does $cov(a, Bc) = cov(a,c)B^T$

Tags: matrices, covariance

Suppose I have a matrix, whereby $$cov(a, Bc) = cov(a,c)B^T$$

Why do we have $B^T$ from the covariance equation, and is this condition strict, when do I know that $$cov(a,Bc) = cov(a,c)B$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x, y$ are random vectors, then the covariance matrix is $xy^T$. Apply this and note that $(Bc)^T = c^TB^T.$ The result follows.

Comment: Ok I see this so $cov(a, Bc) = E[(a)(Bc)^T] - E(a)E(Bc)$ because of independence, we have the desired result.

Comment: This says nothing about independence.